# Log4J is not archiving logs properly

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to configure a log4j for my application. I want it to roll daily, meaning that I want it to create a new text file with logs and archive the old ones. For some reason, my logger deletes old logs and writes over them WITHOUT archiving old logs.

When I changed it to roll every minute, it works with no issues. Every minute it archives my logs and writes new ones.

When I changed it to roll every hour, the same problem occurs as in the case of rolling it daily. It just simply erases old logs without archiving them.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction? Thank you.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1 
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender


log4j.appender.A1.File=C\:Desktop\\MyLogs\\data.log


#log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd  rolls daily
#rolls every minute
#log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm

#rolls every hour
log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH  

log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}|%-5p|%c:%m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running a Weblogic server on my local machine on which I am testing my application. 
It appears that every time you make any changes to a log4j properties file you need to restart the server for changes to take an effect. I was republishing the project without restarting the server.

The logger configuration above is working fine for both minute and hour logging. I will test the daily logging tonight, but I am sure that everything will be in order.

If anyone is interested, here are my Maven dependencies for the logger:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>   

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```